Understanding history reference operator with Custom Functions in Pine Script
I am trying to understand how to use history reference operator with custom functions in Pine Script Version 5 to better understand the usages of history reference operator.
I have seen the following code in tradingView
momEma = ta.ema(close,length) - ta.ema(close, length)[1]

In this example, the history reference operator is used to access the EMA value from a bar ago. The difference between the current EMA value and the EMA from a bar prior to the current bar is then stored in the momEMA series variable.
As per the definition of history reference variable: The operator can only be applied with series-type variables, each time the Pine Script engine updates a series variable and advances to the next bar, the previously updated value becomes part of its history. Which can be referenced using the history reference operator.
For example
a = close + open 

In this code, the variable a is updated with a new value on each bar. To access the value of a from a bar ago, we can use:
a[1]

Now,
Does it mean that ta.ema returns a series type variable?
Secondly,
I wrote a custom function, but haven't been able to use history reference operator with it.
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay =true)

add(a,b) => a+b
result = add(open,close)


if ( barstate.islast)
    // prints the information on the last bar
   
    string txt = "add(open,close)=" + str.tostring(add(open,close), "#.##") + ", add(opne,close)[1]=" + str.tostring(add(open,close)[1], "#.##") + ", add(open,close)[2]=" + str.tostring(add(open,close)[2], "#.##") 
    label.new(chart.point.from_index(bar_index, high), txt, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color.black, label.style_label_left, color.white, size.normal)

Output Image
I am getting NaN in the output.
I know I can save function's output in a series-type variable and can then use that variable with the history reference operator.
However, I would like to understand.
How does this history reference operator works with functions (internal as well as custom functions)?
Can we really use this history reference operator with custom functions?
If no, why?
if Yes, how?
Thanks in Advance!


Does it mean that ta.ema returns a series type variable?

Yes. You can simply check the return type from the reference manual.
ta.ema(source, length) → series float

Coming to the second part of your question, you are breaking history by letting the script only getting executed starting from the last bar by creating your label within if (barstate.islast). Therefore, you won't have enough history to be shown in your label. If you wait for 3 bars to be formed after you add your script to your chart, you will no longer see NaN.
Alternatively, you can do your calculations outside of that if block and then show the results in that if block.
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay =true)

add(a,b) => a+b
result = add(open,close)
result_1 = add(open,close)[1]
result_2 = add(open,close)[2]

if ( barstate.islast)
    // prints the information on the last bar   
    string txt = "add(open,close)=" + str.tostring(add(open,close), "#.##") + ", add(opne,close)[1]=" + str.tostring(add(open,close)[1], "#.##") + ", add(open,close)[2]=" + str.tostring(add(open,close)[2], "#.##") 
    label.new(chart.point.from_index(bar_index, high), txt, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color.black, label.style_label_left, color.white, size.normal)

